# Is there a site for mechanical design and mechanical automation on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site for questions about mechanical design and mechanical automation on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Consider looking at [the list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) when you wonder what's available on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) has a [[mechanical-engineering]](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering) tag, which seems to be close to what you are looking for.

Here is [an example question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212/can-mechanical-design-help-meet-emc-emi-requirements-for-electronic-products) on that site about mechanical design.